# Проблема с триггером в SQL

Tags: sql

Есть таблица

```
[Active] | [DeactivationDate]
true     |      null
false    | 22.03.2017 0:00:00
```

Как можно написать триггер, который срабатывал бы при изменении данных (UPDATE).
И если данные изменялись таким образом, что в Active значение с true менялось на false, то менять значение DeactivationDate с NULL на (getdate()).

А если с false менялось на true, то выдавать ошибку и не записывать такое изменение

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Какой конкретно SQL (у всех СУБД свои языки для написания триггеров) и что вы сами уже пытались сделать

Comment: MSSQL
Я получил данные из inserted и deleted, но не могу их сравнить и предпринять какие-либо действия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь, у вашей таблицы есть идентификатор (id), в таком случае можно так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tru_table1
   ON  dbo.table1
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN   
    update t
    set DeactivationDate=getdate()
    from table1 t inner join deleted d on d.id=t.id
    where t.Active=0 and d.active=1
END
```

Comment: Это сработало, но не могли бы ли Вы объяснить почему, что за конструкция set from?

Comment: Когда происходить обновление в таблице, который связывается с другой таблицей (в данном случае deleted) с помощью `INNER JOIN`, применяется подобная конструкция. Подробности можете найти в учебниках по MS SQL.

Comment: я понимаю вот всё, в этой команде, кроме конструкции, set from.

Comment: команда DeactivationDate=getdate() срабатывает в том случае, если этот запрос содержит в себе хотя бы одну строку?

Comment: Любой select подобным образом можно переделать в Update, например:
`select a.id,a.column1, b.column2
from table1 a inner join table 2 b on a.id=b.id`
можно переделать в Update, заменив первую строчку:
`update a set column1 =b.column2
from table1 a inner join table 2 b on a.id=b.id`
Обновление происходить, если соответствующий select содержит строк.